# Pytorch installation issue under Anaconda

Tags: anaconda, pytorch, fast-ai

I followed the link here to install fastai library using `pip install git+https://github.com/fastai/fastai.git`

It gave me the following error message. These messages keep the same even I installed Pytorch successfully  using  `conda install pytorch-cpu -c pytorch` 
and `pip3 install torchvision`. What can be the reason?

```
Collecting torch<0.4 (from fastai==0.7.0)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/e9/bac4204fe9cb1a002ec6140b47f51affda1655379fe302a1caef421f9846/torch-0.1.2.post1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\shuxi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7sjptuad\torch\setup.py", line 11, in <module>
        raise RuntimeError(README)
    RuntimeError: PyTorch does not currently provide packages for PyPI (see status at https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/566).

    Please follow the instructions at http://pytorch.org/ to install with miniconda instead.


    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\shuxi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7sjptuad\torch\
```

Answer (score 3):

To fix this, do:

```
$ pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/fastai/fastai.git
```

OR

```
$ pip install --no-cache-dir git+https://github.com/fastai/fastai.git
```

Your command probably failed because you have installed a old version of torch (0.1.2) some time ago. `pip` was not supported for torch install for that version and pip instead redirected the user to open pytorch.org in the browser. In your case, pip is reusing this cached package. `--upgrade` forces pip to choose latest version of all depending packages.